# Error while calculating percentage in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the percentage of orders according to three different cases as mentioned in the CASES part of the code. The value for each case shows the percentage value as '1' when I run the code. I think the problem is in the last line of the code, how can I fix this?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF_GRP,ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT(ORDER_ID))*100/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(A.ORDER_ID)) FROM A),2)||'%' AS PERCENTAGE_ORDERS  FROM A
GROUP BY DATEDIFF_GRP ;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't normally use `||` for string concatenation, you have to enable some non-default options to get this.

What is happening is that MySQL is instead interpreting `||` as the logical `OR` operator.  To avoid this problem completely, consider using the `CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF_GRP,
    CONCAT(100 * ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT(ORDER_ID)) /
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(A.ORDER_ID)) FROM A), 2), '%') AS PERCENTAGE_ORDERS
FROM A;
```

You *could* also potentially fix your problem by enabling `ANSI` mode, but as commented below, few MySQL users use the database in this mode.

Comment: The query isn't working. Try `SELECT .75 || '%'` and see that it returns `1`.

Comment: You have me convinced.  Technically speaking, you should cast your count to `CHAR(50)` before calling `CONCAT`.  Had the OP done this, then concatenation via `||` might have actually worked.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Try: `select '50' || '%';`

Comment: Practically no one runs MySQL in ANSI mode.

Comment: @barmar Thanks the code line that you mentioned, in the beginning, using CONCAT() function worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below  - it seems to me that you are trying to concat using `||` operator but mysql support `concat()` function not `||` operator

```
WITH A AS (SELECT OS.ACTUAL_DISPATCH_DATE,OT.ORDER_ID,OT.First_msg_date,datediff(OT.First_msg_date,OS.ACTUAL_DISPATCH_DATE) AS DATEDIFF,
CASE WHEN  datediff(OT.First_msg_date,OS.ACTUAL_DISPATCH_DATE)<=0 THEN 'OTIF' 
    WHEN  datediff(OT.First_msg_date,OS.ACTUAL_DISPATCH_DATE)=1 THEN 'OTIF+1'
    WHEN  datediff(OT.First_msg_date,OS.ACTUAL_DISPATCH_DATE)=2 THEN 'OTIF+2'
    ELSE  'OTIF+>2'
END as DATEDIFF_GRP
FROM order_shipment OS RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT ORDER_ID,MIN((str_to_date(SUBSTRING(MESSAGE,INSTR(MESSAGE,'2'),10),'%Y-%m-%d'))) AS First_msg_date 
FROM ORDER_TIMELINE
GROUP BY ORDER_ID ) OT
ON (OS.ORDER_ID=OT.ORDER_ID)) 
SELECT DATEDIFF_GRP,concat(ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT(ORDER_ID))*100/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(A.ORDER_ID)) FROM A),2),'%') AS PERCENTAGE_ORDERS  
FROM A
GROUP BY DATEDIFF_GRP ;
```

Comment: The OP's query seems to already be running.  Your suggestion, while possibly a good one, would not seem to be able to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @fa06, I tried the above code, and whenever I use cast, my query shows a syntax error. Error: 'WITH' is not a valid position for this server version. expecting '(', SELECT

Comment: @AnonymousPython, I've updated it - there was a bracket missing

Comment: It's not necessary to use `CAST`. MySQL automatically casts numbers to strings when they're used in `CONCAT()`.